# Passing a variable to a server using ThreadingMixIn, tensorflow

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I have python3 code which is implementing HttpServer with ThreadingMixIn.
Problem is that I have a complex tensorflow computation which is run when the server is started.

when `longComputation  = Long_Computation()` is inside (the threaded)`RequestHandler` it works but it is too time consuming to rebuild the request every time

When it is out, as the code below, I get

### TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: The name 'save/Const:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'save/Const', does not exist in the graph.

```
longComputation  = Long_Computation()

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
            # if i add longComputation  = Long_Computation() here, it works but reruns code for each request
            self.send_response(200) 
            self.end_headers()
            self.send_header('Content-type','application/json')
            length = int(self.headers['content-length'])
            data = self.rfile.read(length).decode('utf-8')

            longComputation.run({'data':data})
            self.wfile.write(bytes(json.dumps({}), "utf8"))
            return  
        return

class ThreadedHTTPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    """Handle requests in a separate thread."""

def run():
    print('starting server...')

    server_address = ('0.0.0.0', PORT)
    httpd = ThreadedHTTPServer(server_address, RequestHandler)
    httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, keyfile='/etc/letsencrypt/live/classifier-icici.nanorep-services.com/privkey.pem', certfile='/etc/letsencrypt/live/classifier-icici.nanorep-services.com/cert.pem', server_side=True)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: When you do not use threading, what problem do you have then?  It works but?

Comment: When I use the threading I get the error above. When I put longComputation  = Long_Computation() inside the (threaded) request it works well, edited the ending

Comment: @JohnZwinck
Yes, works as soon I remove threading